# Breadcrumps stick at the top laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, breadcrumbs

I am trying to make my breadcrumbs stick to the top but for some reason, when I try to do it there is a gap in between as shown in screenshot. The breadcrumb I have right now is able to stick to the top when I scroll down. The only problem is the gap only. Can someone help me here, thanks a lot

Screenshot:
[image]
Code:

```
       <div class = "container" style=" position: fixed; left: 0; top:55px; width: 100%;">
          {{ Breadcrumbs::render('personal.edit',$id) }}
        </div>
    @section('content')

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#C0C0C0; padding-top: 60px; position: relative;">

//content
...
...
```

Comment: Z-Indexing, is what it looks like.  It's behind another element on the page.  Put `z-index:1000;` to test it.  It's better to add fixed elements in latter in the page because then they don't get stacked on top of.

Comment: Your first breadcrumb probably has a margin left. If you change the background color of the first container you will probably see that it does not have a gap. Try adding background:blue to the styles. Also as mentioned above you need to change the z-index.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the z-indexing works but can I ask what does that do? I never really saw much people talk about it

Comment: @iSZ I tried changing the color all it does was make it blue instead of silver but it ok ArtisticPhoenix has solved the question, thank you for helping :)

Comment: @blastme no problem. Z-index changes staking level of the items. Your .container probably has it in your css.

Comment: you mean how it is stack @iSZ?

Comment: @blastme Yep like stacked transparencies in animation layers

Comment: yea so what you should do is moved the fixed content after the other container, then it will be rendered latter and you wont need the zindex.  It can be bad to leave it because it can mess with popups etc.  Sort of like doing float right before float left, but backwards.

Comment: Ohh I see thank you guys for helping me and teaching me :)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix could you post your answer so I will mark it as correct and also with the explination

Comment: I would but I have to run out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `z-index` issue.  Z-Index is like layers or the stacking order of elements on the page. So to me it looks like one of the container divs are rendering on top of your breadcrumbs element ( which is positioned fixed.).

You can test it by adding `z-index:1000;` to the elements style.

Often this can be fixed simply by moving the element lower in the page so that it renders after the stuff that is showing up above it in the stack.  It's generally a bad idea to set the z-index arbitrarily as this can have negative consequences with things like menu drop downs and popups, which need a high z-index value.  Then you wind up with the opposite issue where your element renders on top of those.

It's a pretty common problem for "position" fixed or abstract elements.